# Woocommerce: Format all product unit prices to 3 decimal places but not for cart and checkout totals

Tags: php, woocommerce, format, price, add-filter

I would like to format all product unit prices to 3 decimal places. This includes the unit prices displayed in the cart and checkout pages.

In my Woocommerce settings under 'Currency Options', I have set the number of decimals to 2, as I want the cart totals, checkout totals and invoice prices to be in 2 decimal places.

Would appreciate any help I can get! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

To set the displayed decimals to 3 in single product pages and archives pages as shop, use:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_price_decimals' , 'custom_price_decimals', 20, 1 );
function custom_price_decimals( $decimals ) {
    if( is_product() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) 
        $decimals = 3;

    return $decimals;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

You can extend and control the use of those decimals custom settings adding [Woocommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)